# Child not respecting its parent's size SwiftUI

Tags: html, ios, swift, swiftui, nsattributedstring

We're currently working on a Twitter-esque Client for SwiftUI and we have to convert HTML content to `NSAttributedString`s. For that reason, we're using [Atributika](https://github.com/psharanda/Atributika) to style the HTML tags. It seems to be working correctly, but when we try to display the content, the text just goes over other content. We've assumed it is because it does not respect its parent's size, but it's probably something else.

[image: our problem]
[image: our problem]

How would we fix this? Is there a better way to render HTML content in SwiftUI that doesn't require using WKWebViews since that will result in an incredible performance drop?

Is there something we're missing?

Thanks in advance.

**Our code**:

**NetworkView.swift**

```
struct NetworkView: View {

    @ObservedObject var timeline = NetworkViewModel()

    private let size: CGFloat = 300
    private let padding: CGFloat = 10
    private let displayPublic: Bool = true

    var body: some View {

        List {
            Section {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("F").padding()) {
                    Label("Announcements", systemImage: "megaphone")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("F").padding()) {
                    Label("Activity", systemImage: "flame")
                }
            }
            .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())

            Section(header:
                Picker(selection: self.$timeline.type, label: Text("Network visibility")) {
                    Text("My community").tag(TimelineScope.local)
                    Text("Public").tag(TimelineScope.public)
                }                        .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                    .padding(.top)
                    .padding(.bottom, 2)) {

                if self.timeline.statuses.isEmpty {

                    HStack {

                        Spacer()

                        VStack {

                            Spacer()

                            ProgressView(value: 0.5)
                                .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle())

                            Text("Loading posts...")

                            Spacer()

                        }

                        Spacer()

                    }

                } else {

                    ForEach(self.timeline.statuses, id: \.self.id) { status in
                        StatusView(status: status)
                            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    }

                }
            }

        }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())

    }
}
```

**StatusView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import Atributika

/// A structure that computes statuses on demand from a `Status` data model.
struct StatusView: View {

    #if os(iOS)
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) private var horizontalSizeClass
    #endif

    /// In Starlight, there are two ways to display mastodon statuses:
    ///     - Standard: The status is being displayed from the feed.
    ///     - Focused: The status is the main post of a thread.
    ///
    /// The ``StatusView`` instance should know what way it is being
    /// displayed so that it can display the content properly.
    /// In order to achieve this, we pass a bool to ``StatusView``, which when true,
    /// tells it that it's content should be displayed as `Focused`.
    private var isMain: Bool

    /// The ``Status`` data model whose the data will be displayed.
    var status: Status

    #if os(iOS)

    /// Using for triggering the navigation View **only**when the user taps
    /// on the content, and not when it taps on the action buttons.
    @State var goToThread: Int? = 0

    @State var showMoreActions: Bool = false

    @State var profileViewActive: Bool = false

    #endif

    private let rootStyle: Style = Style("p")
        .font(.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .light))
    private let rootPresentedStyle: Style = Style("p")
        .font(.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .light))
    
    private func configureLabel(_ label: AttributedLabel, size: CGFloat = 17) {
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textColor = .label
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: size)
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    }

    /// To easily use the same view on multiple platforms,
    /// we use the `body` view as a container where we load platform-specific
    /// modifiers.
    var body: some View {

        //  We use this vertical stack to load platform specific modifiers,
        //  or to load specific views when a condition is met.
        VStack {

            // Whether the post is focused or not.
            if self.isMain {

                self.presentedView

            } else {

                // To provide the best experience, we want to allow the user to easily
                // interact with a post directly from the feed. Because of that, we need
                // to add a button
                ZStack {

                    self.defaultView

                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: ThreadView(mainStatus: self.status),
                        tag: 1,
                        selection: self.$goToThread,
                        label: {
                            EmptyView()
                        }
                    )

                }

            }

        }
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

    }

    /// The status display mode when it is the thread's main post.
    var presentedView: some View {

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {

            NavigationLink(destination:
                            ProfileView(isParent: false,
                                        accountInfo: ProfileViewModel(accountID: self.status.account.id),
                                        onResumeToParent: {
                                            self.profileViewActive = false
                                        }),
                           isActive: self.$profileViewActive) {
                EmptyView()
            }

            HStack(alignment: .center) {

                ProfileImage(from: self.status.account.avatarStatic, placeholder: {
                    Circle()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                })

                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {

                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                        Text("\(self.status.account.displayName)")
                            .font(.headline)

                        Text("\(self.status.account.acct)")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .lineLimit(1)

                    }

                }

                Spacer()

                Button(action: { self.showMoreActions.toggle() }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                })
            }

            GeometryReader { (geometry: GeometryProxy) in
                AttributedTextView(attributedText:
                                    "\(self.status.content)"
                                        .style(tags: rootPresentedStyle),
                                   configured: { label in configureLabel(label, size: 20) },
                                   maxWidth: geometry.size.width)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
            }

            if !self.status.mediaAttachments.isEmpty {
                AttachmentView(from: self.status.mediaAttachments[0].url) {
                    Rectangle()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
            }

            HStack {
                Text("\(self.status.createdAt.getDate()!.format(as: "hh:mm · dd/MM/YYYY")) · ")
                Button(action: {

                    if let application = self.status.application {
                        if let website = application.website {
                            openUrl(website)
                        }
                    }

                }, label: {
                    Text("\(self.status.application?.name ?? "Mastodon")")
                        .lineLimit(1)
                })
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    .padding(.leading, -7)
            }
                .padding(.top)

            Divider()

            Text("\(self.status.repliesCount.roundedWithAbbreviations) ").bold()
            +
            Text("comments, ")
            +
            Text("\(self.status.reblogsCount.roundedWithAbbreviations) ").bold()
            +
            Text("boosts, and ")
            +
            Text("\(self.status.favouritesCount.roundedWithAbbreviations) ").bold()
            +
            Text("likes.")

            Divider()

            self.actionButtons
                .padding(.vertical, 5)
                .padding(.horizontal)

        }
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        .navigationBarHidden(self.profileViewActive)
        .actionSheet(isPresented: self.$showMoreActions) {
            ActionSheet(title: Text("More Actions"),
                        buttons: [
                            .default(Text("View @\(self.status.account.acct)'s profile"), action: {
                                self.profileViewActive = true
                            }),
                            .destructive(Text("Mute @\(self.status.account.acct)"), action: {

                            }),
                            .destructive(Text("Block @\(self.status.account.acct)"), action: {

                            }),
                            .destructive(Text("Report @\(self.status.account.acct)"), action: {

                            }),
                            .cancel(Text("Dismiss"), action: {})
                        ]
            )
        }

    }

    var defaultView: some View {

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {

            Button(action: {
                self.goToThread = 1
            }, label: {
                HStack(alignment: .top) {

                    ProfileImage(from: self.status.account.avatarStatic, placeholder: {
                        Circle()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    })

                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {

                        HStack {

                            HStack(spacing: 5) {

                                Text("\(self.status.account.displayName)")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .lineLimit(1)

                                Text("\(self.status.account.acct)")
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                    .lineLimit(1)

                                Text("· \(self.status.createdAt.getDate()!.getInterval())")
                                    .lineLimit(1)

                            }

                        }

                        GeometryReader { (geometry: GeometryProxy) in
                            AttributedTextView(attributedText:
                                                "\(self.status.content)"
                                                    .style(tags: rootStyle),
                                               configured: { label in configureLabel(label, size: 17) },
                                               maxWidth: geometry.size.width)
                                .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
                        }

                        if !self.status.mediaAttachments.isEmpty {
                            AttachmentView(from: self.status.mediaAttachments[0].previewURL) {
                                Rectangle()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
            })

            self.actionButtons
                .padding(.leading, 60)

        }
            .contextMenu(
                ContextMenu(menuItems: {

                    Button(action: {}, label: {
                        Label("Report post", systemImage: "flag")
                    })

                    Button(action: {}, label: {
                        Label("Report \(self.status.account.displayName)", systemImage: "flag")
                    })

                    Button(action: {}, label: {
                        Label("Share as Image", systemImage: "square.and.arrow.up")
                    })

                })
            )

    }

    /// The post's action buttons (favourite and reblog), and also the amount of replies.
    ///
    /// If the post is focused (``isMain`` is true), the count is hidden.
    var actionButtons: some View {
        HStack {

            HStack {

                Image(systemName: "text.bubble")

                if !self.isMain {
                    Text("\(self.status.repliesCount.roundedWithAbbreviations)")
                }

            }

            Spacer()

            Button(action: {

            }, label: {

                HStack {

                    Image(systemName: "arrow.2.squarepath")

                    if !self.isMain {
                        Text("\(self.status.reblogsCount.roundedWithAbbreviations)")
                    }

                }

            })
                .foregroundColor(
                    labelColor
                )

            Spacer()

            Button(action: {

            }, label: {

                HStack {

                    Image(systemName: "heart")

                    if !self.isMain {
                        Text("\(self.status.favouritesCount.roundedWithAbbreviations)")
                    }
                }

            })
                .foregroundColor(
                    labelColor
                )

            Spacer()

            Button(action: {

            }, label: {

                Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")

            })
                .foregroundColor(
                    labelColor
                )

        }

    }

}

extension StatusView {

    /// Generates a View that displays a post on Mastodon.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - isPresented: A boolean variable that determines whether
    ///     the status is being shown as the main post (in a thread).
    ///     - status: The identified data that the ``StatusView`` instance uses to
    ///     display posts dynamically.
    public init(isMain: Bool = false, status: Status) {
        self.isMain = isMain
        self.status = status
    }

}

struct StatusView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    @ObservedObject static var timeline = NetworkViewModel()

    static var previews: some View {
        VStack {
            if self.timeline.statuses.isEmpty {
                HStack {

                    Spacer()

                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        ProgressView(value: 0.5)
                            .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle())
                        Text("Loading status...")
                        Spacer()
                    }

                    Spacer()

                }
                    .onAppear {
                        self.timeline.fetchLocalTimeline()
                    }
            } else {
                StatusView(isMain: false, status: self.timeline.statuses[0])
            }
        }
            .frame(width: 600, height: 300)
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
```

**AttributedTextView.swift**

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Atributika

// Note: Implementation pulled from pending PR in Atributika on GitHub: https://github.com/psharanda/Atributika/pull/119
// Credit to rivera-ernesto for this implementation.

/// A view that displays one or more lines of text with applied styles.
struct AttributedTextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = RestrainedLabel

    /// The attributed text for this view.
    var attributedText: AttributedText?

    /// The configuration properties for this view.
    var configured: ((AttributedLabel) -> Void)?

    @State var maxWidth: CGFloat = 300

    public func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<AttributedTextView>) -> RestrainedLabel {
        let new = RestrainedLabel()
        configured?(new)
        return new
    }

    public func updateUIView(_ uiView: RestrainedLabel, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<AttributedTextView>) {
        uiView.attributedText = attributedText
        uiView.maxWidth = maxWidth
    }

    class RestrainedLabel: AttributedLabel {
        var maxWidth: CGFloat = 0.0

        open override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
            sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: maxWidth, height: .infinity))
        }
    }

}
```